# Do lossless compression algorithms work on the bit level?

Tags: c, algorithm, compression, lossless-compression

Let's for example say that I have a file, and I want to create a compression algorithm in C, should my algorithm get the bit representation of that file, work on it and write a new file that only my algorithm would know how to uncompress?

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of answer you're looking for here. Have you studied any lossless compression schemes? This might be a good place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but yes any practical compression algorithm will need to write arbitrary numbers of bits to the output.

Comment: "Do lossless compression algorithms work on the bit level?" --> some do, some do not.  As to what you should do, step 1: code via what every algorithm you best understand.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding is concerned more with probabilities than bits

Comment: *Plain Input* usually is interpreted using *smallest addressable units* - bytes, mostly. *Compressed/encoded IO* used to be done with variable bit length codes, and has gone [beyond](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding).

Comment: (Try creating a compressor producing output shorter than ["the BSD compress(1)"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch#Variable-width_codes) implementation of LZW, but decompressible by any compatible implementation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The intuition behind simple file compression

Consider mapping ***M: K -> V***.

The requirements for such a mapping is that any input string ***k*** can be specifically mapped to some hopefully shorter string ***M(k) = v***.

### Example (with text)

Your input file is

```
aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccaaaaaaaaaa
```

Compression algorithm should find some mapping ***M*** that would offer nice compression, without taking too long to do it. 
In this case, intuitively, you could use:

```
M(aaaaaaaaaa) = a
M(bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb) = b
M(ccccc) = c
```

And the compressed file becomes

```
abca
```

You can decompress the file doing the same thing in reverse.

*(note that the mapping needs to be somehow stored alongside/inside the compressed file, so that you know how to decompress it later)*

#### Now you can probably already guess that this is best done at bit level where your strings are individual bits.

### Example (with bits)

Your input file is

```
11111111101010101010101010101010101010000000000000
```

Compression algorithm should find some mapping ***M*** that would offer nice compression, without taking too long to do it. 
In this case, intuitively, you could use:

```
M(111111111) = 11
M(0101010101010101010101010101) = 01
M(0000000000000) = 00
```

And the compressed file becomes

```
110100
```

A strong advantage of doing it at the bit level is that it can be used for any file type.

Comment: Nice! I though so.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by 'this is best done at bit level where your strings attached the individual bits...'? Thanks

Comment: @SahilChhabra added an example for bit-level file compression